# How do I get all of the property names from a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to get all properties name of a model which is init on run time in HtmlHelper extension. I cannot use Type.GetType inside helper because it returns null.

Model Code:

```
public class SampleVm
{
    public object ResultObject { get; set; }

    public dynamic ResultDynamic { get; set; }
}
```

View Code:

```
@Html.SampleResult(m => m. ResultDynamic)    // this is error, I don’t know why
@Html.SampleResult(m => m. ResultObject)   // this works
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SearchVm vm = new SearchVm();
    vm.ResultObject = Type.GetType("MvcApplication4.Models.Sample.SampleMasterModel");
    vm.ResultDynamic = Type.GetType("MvcApplication4.Models.Sample.SampleMasterModel");
    return View("Index", vm);
}
```

HtmlHelper extension Code:

```
public static HtmlString SearchResult<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    TModel model = html.ViewData.Model;
    String propertiesName = ?????
    // I want to get the properties name from ResultDynamic or ResultObject
    // I can found all properties from ResultDynamic in debug but don’t know how to 
    // get it.  For ResultDynamic, I don't know how to get the properties name.
    return new HtmlString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Type.GetType in help with AssemblyQualifiedName.  It solve the problems.

```
var type = Type.GetType("AssemblyQualifiedName of my Type");

var properties = type.GetProperties();
```

Thanks
Wilson